# vimの矩形編集がうまくいかない

Tags: vim

これと同じことをやっているのですがうまくいきません
https://qiita.com/ebisu7/items/f43beb322d0dd1bbe3e4

ビジュアルモードにして矩形選択後

shift+iをおしても 挿入モードに移行しません。
2回目shift+iをおすと移行します。

escを押しても選択範囲に挿入されません。

なぜでしょうか？

**環境**
windows10
vagrant
vartualbox
putty
vim version 7.4.629

**$ vi -v としたときの表示内容**
          VIM - Vi IMproved
~
~                               version 7.4.629
~                           by Bram Moolenaar et al.
~                      Modified by 
~                 Vim is open source and freely distributable
~
~                        Help poor children in Uganda!
~                type  :help iccf       for information
~
~                type  :q               to exit
~                type  :help  or    for on-line help
~                type  :help version7   for version info

Comment: `vim -u NONE -U NONE -N` で起動して試してみてください．これでうまく行った場合設定ファイルに関係しそうな記述がないか見てみるのが早いと思います．

Comment: だめでした。。。。。。。。。。

Answer (score 7, accepted):

お使いのVimが、vim-tinyとかvim-smallと言われる、機能制約版（最小構成版）なのかと思います。

矩形ビジュアル挿入など、矩形選択時の様々な操作を使うには、
`+visualextra`機能が有効になっている必要があります。（コンパイル時のオプションです）

参考: https://vim-jp.org/vimdoc-ja/visual.html#blockwise-operators

コンパイル時に決まるVimの種類は、下記の5つがあります（上に行くほど機能が制限されている）

- tiny
- small
- normal
- big
- huge

そして、`+visualextra`が有効になるのは、normal以上のもの（normal, big, huge）です。

参考: https://vim-jp.org/vimdoc-ja/various.html#+visualextra

---

```
$ vim --version
```

の出力に、`Small version without GUI.`とか`-visualextra`があれば、上述の機能制限版のVimですので、矩形ビジュアル挿入は使えません。何らかの方法でフル機能が使えるVimをインストールしてみてください。

Comment: そういうような表示はありませんでしたがVIM - Vi IMproved
~
~                                    version 7.4.629　と表示されました。vi -vでしかバージョン確認できません。わたしが使っているのはそもそもvimじゃないんでしょうか？

Comment: VIM - Vi IMproved という内容が含まれているようなのでvimだとは思います。`vi --version`を実行したときに出力される内容を質問内容に追加してもらえますか？

Comment: -質問内容を、編集しました。-

Comment: 確認しました。`-v`はバージョン情報を出力するオプションではないので、普通にvimが起動しています。`vi -v`ではなくて、`vi --version`の結果を教えてください。（シェルでlsコマンドを実行したときにファイル一覧が表示されるのと同じように、標準出力にバージョン情報が出力されています）

Comment: ありがとうございます。$ vi --versionで確認した結果smallバージョンであることが確認できました。